# Android: Call Method in another class

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity called new_position, which i use to locate the current gps coordinates. I created a Listener class used in requestLocationUpdates. When my onLocationChanged method in my Listener class gets called i want to call a method in my new_position class. But it only seems to work when i make my class static, but i don't want to make it static. is there another way?

```
public class Listener implements LocationListener {

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {        
    new_position.lati = location.getLatitude();
    new_position.longi = location.getLongitude();

    new_position.SaveCoordinates(new_position.str_posname);
}
```

Comment: as I understand, your Listener class is defined inner to the activity?? and the activity class is new_position, then use this: `new_position.this.whateverthemethod()`

Comment: you can make an object of `new_position` and call the function using `.`(dot) operator, like `object.function();`

Comment: @eduyayo my Listener class is not defined in the new_position activity, i just creat a new instance of it in my activity `mLocLis = new Listener();`

Comment: Make `Application` class and use it to save global variables, you can call this class in any Android component using `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: no offense @user370305 you´re killing flys with cannons... Just define the listener inline and use the `whatevertheactivityclass.whatevermethod()`

Comment: @Lal but if i create a new object from new_position all the changes in this object wouldn't effect my values in my running actitivity or am i wrong?

Comment: Nothing will be affected.. @Verdemis..Try it..

Comment: @eduyayo - I am suggesting the best way to access variables required in different android components as per global use. And after that it wont be applicable to only one activity or scope of Listener class.

Comment: pls, notice he´s using a bad programming practice trying to access an agreggator variable for a trivial operation. Those globals have other purposes

Comment: @Verdemis , please follow java tutorials and android examples where they define inline classes and use them

Comment: Where have u initialized Listener class? in new_position?

Comment: @Harry I have a method in new_position `private void GetMyLocation(){
        mLocMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocLis = new Listener();
        mLocNetLis = new Listener();

        mLocMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,mLocNetLis);        
        mLocMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocLis);

    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as simple as below:

```
public class Listener implements LocationListener {

Context c;
public Listener(Context c)
{
    this.c=c;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {        
    ...

    ((new_position)c).SaveCoordinates(...);
}
}
```

initialize class object with mLocNetLis = new Listener(new_position.this);

Hope this helped!